# Is it possible to add a function to a class using .NET reflection?

Tags: .net, reflection

Is it possible to add a function to a class using reflection in .NET?

For instance, could I write code that would add a function to a class that adds two Int32s and returns the result?

This is assuming that there isn't any such function already compiled into the system, so what I have in mind is basically converting a string to a function, similar to what JavaScript does with "eval" (and yes, I know that `eval` is *evil*).

Comment: Short answer: "no". Slightly longer answer: "extension methods"

Comment: You can't really add methods to *existing* classes, but you can add *new* assemblies and classes, e.g. with [emitting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to create assemblies on runtime using a few approaches:

- Using [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/roslyn) (currently in CTP) you should be able to compile an arbitrary piece of .NET code into an assembly and it works painlessly. This currently is the most painless way of doing runtime code generation.
- You can do it the hard(er) way, by ILWeaving. This basically is emitting IL code at runtime and you can not only generate new classes/functions,etc. but you can modify existing ones. A few ones already out there are INotifyPropertyChanged interface implementation through [ILWeaving](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/02/IL-Weaving). You still need to have a good understanding of [IL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) to do this.
- Using some kind of [Aspect framework](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/). These frameworks do the heavy lifting for you so you don't write the IL code. Usually the necessary code is generated for you at compile time.
- Using [Dynamic Proxies](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) you can also have some control on what your existing code will do, say, if you're interested doing something before/after an existing method/function of a class.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to emit the class as well, so no you can't add, and it's painful as well.

Have a look at using a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) dynamic languages [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) and even java (well ECMA) script are all available.

Based on your comment to Mitch's answer, another thing you might want to look at the is the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event. You can do fun things like keep your assembly in a database blob with that.

You'll need to do some serious planning ahead with that route though.

Comment: Tore out the link to Java that was edited in, as I was referring to Javascript, which is not the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.  You can only read from the functions in the class already, you can't add to it.  Anyway why would you need to?  Just write the code you want to add to it in your current program.

Comment: I was just curious.  I was wondering if it might be possible to deploy an application and then change the applications logic by have the application read new code from somewhere without pushing a new assembly.

Comment: What in the world for?  Either way you are "push"ing something.  What reason would you want to push source instead of assembly?

Comment: Here's what I have in mind: I would like to have an application call to a web service and pass some information.  I would like the web service to pass back some information describing some function to be executed later.

Comment: Then could you not just create a function that handles various inputs and returns based on the input? Or even use a delegate?